# How can I make something be compatible with both an array and a collection?

Tags: java, bukkit

It sounds a stupid question. However, in the API that I am using, version 1.7.2 has got the method `Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()` returning a `Player[]`, and version 1.7.10 has got `Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()` returning a `Collection<Player>`. I need to make my plugin compatible with both.

I have got the API's for both, but aside from creating separate plugins, I currently have got no idea how to do this.

I currently just convert the collection into an array anyway. So, is there any way to (i can already get the version) if the version is less than 1.7.9, not use the `.toArray()` but since it already returns an array?

Comment: You could do it with reflection.

Comment: Are you saying the first method (returning an array) was removed from the later version of the library?

Comment: @BasilBourque That's correct. The new ones return a collection, but the old versions don't. There was a brief moment of backward compatibility in 1.7.10, but it vanished in 1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with reflection. Something like this:

```
List<Player> getPlayers() {
    try {
        Method method = getMethod(Server.class, "getOnlinePlayers");
        Object result = method.invoke(Bukkit.getServer());
        if(result instanceof Player[])
            return Arrays.asList((Player[])result);
        else
            return (List<Player>)result;

    } catch(ReflectiveOperationException e) {

        // something went wrong! If you have a better way to handle problems, do that instead
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over the method answered above? Thanks.

Comment: I liked both solutions, but I think I like yours better. Thank you.

Comment: @Unheilig You mean the advantage of this over AlexR's method? This one actually works.

Comment: @immibis: For better readability, I would recommend to first assign Bukkit.getServer() to a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two ways to do this. @immibis's answer gives the first way.  The second way involves creating a "version adapter" API with multiple plugin implementations for different versions of (in this case) Bukkit; e.g.

```
public interface BukkitVersionAdapter {
    Collection<Player> getOnlinePlayers();
    ...
}

public class BukkitVersionAdapterV1dot7 implements BukkitVersionAdapter {
    public Collection<Player> getOnlinePlayers() {
        return Arrays.asList(Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers());
    }
    ...
}

public class BukkitVersionAdapterV1dot8 implements BukkitVersionAdapter {
    public Collection<Player> getOnlinePlayers() {
        return Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers();
    }
    ...
}
```

The version-specific adapter classes then need to be compiled against the Bukkit API jars for the respective Bukkit versions.

Then when you start your main application (or Bukkit plugin I guess), you do something like this:

```
String version = // get the Bukkit version
String className = // map the version to a class name; e.g.
                   // "pkg.BukkitVersionAdapterV1dot7" or
                   // "pkg.BukkitVersionAdapterV1dot8"
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
BukkitVersionAdapter adapter = 
         (BukkitVersionAdapter) clazz.newInstance();

// Then ...
Collection<Player> players = adapter.getOnlinePlayers();
```

---

This is all rather cumbersome, but it has two benefits compared with the approach of using reflection to make the calls:

1. The logic that is specific to different Bukkit versions is now isolated to one part of the codebase ... rather than being scattered (potentially) all over the place.
2. The overheads of reflection are only incurred at startup.  After that, all of the method calls to Bukkit made via the adapter API are regular Java method calls.

Depending on the context, these *may* make the adapter approach more appropriate.

Comment: `(BukkitVersionAdapter) Class.newInstance();` should be `(BukkitVersionAdapter) clazz.newInstance();`

Comment: You also have to compile the adapter classes separately, with the corresponding Bukkit version.

Comment: @Unihedro - I said "something like ..." and `Class` is something like `clazz`.  :-)  But I've corrected it anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the class `org.bukkit.Server` just changed the return type of the method `getOnlinePlayers()` rather than making it deprecated and introducing a new method (yack!!!!! who dares to change the already published interface in such a way?), you have no decent way how to call the method in one single code. You simply **cannot** write something like

```
Server server = Bukkit.getServer();
// One of the branches will not be compilable
if (version <= xxxx) {
    Player[] players = server.getOnlinePlayers();
}
else {
    Collection<Player> players = server.getOnlinePlayers();
}
```

I'm afraid the only way is to use reflection like in the meantime others recommended.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing well. Unfortunately there is no way to create strongly typed method that can deal with both collection and array.

(You can create method that accepts `Object` and then examine it using `instanceof`, cast and deal with both collection and arrays but this solution is ugly.)

Comment: You can't just do `Object o = Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers()`, because the compiler still decides at compile-time what the method returns, and uses that in the bytecode.